# Spring Batch Multiple Database Configuration for Data Replication

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I have a series of tables in a source database that I need to replicate into a destination database.  This process has the following requirements:

- Replicated records must be removed from source.
- Destination records may require some form of data transformation.
- Process must be multithreaded to minimize replication time.

In looking at Spring Batch's core *ItemReaders* and *ItemWriters*, I could elect to use JDBC, JPA, or even Hibernate-centric implementations.  My goal would be to leverage existing entity definitions if possible for these tables and thus JPA or Hibernate would be the ideal choice where possible.

I am starting with the JPA implementation in hopes to customize it where possible to use the Hibernate Stateless Session API for bulk operations where applicable for performance.

So I defined my *JpaPagingItemReader*(s) as follows:

```
<bean id="jpaPagingItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" abstract="true">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="srcEntityManagerFactory" />
  <property name="transacted" value="false" />
  <property name="pageSize" value="15000" />
  <property name="saveState" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="table1Reader" parent="jpaPagingItemReader" scope="step">
  <property name="queryString" value="FROM Item1 i WHERE i.facility = '#{stepExecutionContext['facilityId']}" />
</bean>

<bean id="table2Reader" parent="jpaPagingItemReader" scope="step">
  <property name="queryString" value="FROM Item2 i WHERE i.facility = '#{stepExecutionContext['facilityId']}" />
</bean>
```

Each reader is defined *step* scope because I need to be able to pass in specific step execution parameters to filter the reader query based on values determined from a partitioner.

I have two processors that are defined simply as follows:

```
<bean id="table1Processor" class="com.comp.batch.transform.Table1Processor" />
<bean id="table2Processor" class="com.comp.batch.transform.Table2Processor" />
```

These two classes simply instantiate the entity class the Writer must use and then copies and transforms the reader item's class properties to the destination entity class properties and nothing more (shown below).  This is merely an example, but the actual code follows this approach.

```
public class Table1Processor implements ItemProcessor<Item1, Item1Result> {
  @Override
  public Item1Result process(Item1 item) {
    Item1Result result = new Item1Result();
    result.setProperty1(item.getProperty1());
    result.setCalculatedValue(2.5d * item.getMeasurement());
    return result;
  }
}
```

For the *JpAItemWriter*:

```
<bean id="jpaItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="dstEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

The job gets defined as

```
<bean id="job" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="false">
  <batch:split id="import" task-executor="taskExecutor">
    <batch:flow>
      <batch:step id="importTable1">
        <batch:partition step="importTable1Partitioned" partitioner="facilityPartitioner">
          <batch:handler task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch>
      </batch>
    </batch:flow>
    <batch:flow>
      <batch:step id="importTable2">
        <batch:partition step="importTable2Partitioned" partitioner="facilityPartitioner">
          <batch:handler task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch>
      </batch>
    </batch:flow>
  </batch:split>
</bean>

<batch:step id="importTable1Partitioned">
  <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor">
    <batch:chunk reader="table1Reader" processor="table1Processor" writer="jpaItemWriter" commit-interval="15000" />
  </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<batch:step id="importTable2Partitioned">
  <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor">
    <batch:chunk reader="table2Reader" processor="table2Processor" writer="jpaItemWriter" commit-interval="15000" />
  </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

My first question is that since I am introducing multiple threads above using chunk oriented processing inside of multiple flows of execution, does anyone see any issues with using the *JpaPagingItemReader* in this fashion?

Secondly, where do I implement the process indicator update within my configuration so that replicated rows that are successfully copied are marked as such so a later step can do a mass delete?  I could be mistaken, but I don't believe the source row can simply be deleted during the same processing step transaction without impacting the paging algorithm?

Lastly, is it possible to take *JpaItemWriter*'s doWrite() method and simply unwrap the EntityManager to Hibernate's session and open a stateless session using the same underlying connection and perform the inserts without bothering with the L1 cache and other stateful mechanics of the JPA provider?

If my configuration or approach is wildly off and there is by far a more ideal approach, please don't hesitate to share as my experience with Spring Batch is still quite green.